# WPF bindings not refreshing

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a listbox on my form that looks like this:

```
<ListBox Name="lbResults" SelectionChanged="lbResults_SelectionChanged"/>
```

I am binding the following collection to it:

```
ObservableCollection<Hand> oHands = new ObservableCollection<Hand>();
```

using the following code:

```
lbResults.DataContext = oHands;
Binding binding = new Binding();
lbResults.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

The oHands collection gets populated via a background worker that announces via an event whenever a new Hand object is available.  The ListBox refreshes perfectly when something is added.  The ToString() result of the Hand object is displayed and that is what I want - so far so good.  However, when the background worker finishes

```
void finder_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            oHands = new ObservableCollection<Hand>(oHands.OrderBy(o => o.PotSize));
            lbResults.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
        }
```

The items in the list are still showing up in the original order.  I can confirm that the list is re-ordered but the items are still showing up in the original order.  How do I refresh this binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont want to assign oHands a new collection.  just Clear() the collection then add the results from the operation.  don't update the binding

Answer (score 1):

instead of replacing the entire observable collection, you could just clear it and add all your new items.  that wouldn't affect your binding.

You could also use a `CollectionViewSource` as your binding, and set the order on that instead of reordering the whole collection.

Comment: ok this worked but I think Alex answered with the same advice a moment earlier.  thank you :)

Comment: its ok, he needs the rep more than me for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You're *really* just supposed to inherit from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but heres another way to force an update to a binding:

```
BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(lbResults, Listbox.ItemsSourceProperty)
exp.UpdateTarget()
```

Edit: I also just noticed you aren't setting any binding in the XAML and appear to be doing it programmatically with an empty Binding. I haven't tried that way before, so see if changing your XAML to this might help:

```
<ListBox Name="lbResults" SelectionChanged="lbResults_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=oHands}"/>
```

Then you set `lbResults.DataContext` to point to the class that has the member `oHands`. This is what worked for me in my project (in IronPython, so forgive me if my examples didn't convert to C# perfectly).

Comment: I updated my worker completed method to look like:

void finder_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
   oHands = new ObservableCollection<Hand>(oHands.OrderBy(o => o.PotSize));
   BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(lbResults, ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
   exp.UpdateTarget();

  }

but it still doesn't show up in the new order :(

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just set the itemsource directly?

```
lbResults.ItemsSource = oHands;
```

Comment: Would that actually update when oHands is changed or reordered?

Comment: Since it's an observablecollection, changes to the collection would change the listbox.  If you sort it and return a new collection, the itemsource will be updated with the new collection.